# Can objects move during a collision-elastic collisions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, collision

Can two objects move together during an elastic collision before moving apart? Or would this be considered an inelastic collision since during the time in which the objects were stuck moving together, the kinetic energy was reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that terms *elastic collision* and *inelastic collision* are just abstractions to indicate certain properties of a collision. To determine if a collision is elastic or inelastic you have to **observe kinetic energy just before and just after the contact**. If kinetic energy is preserved the collision is said to be **elastic**, and if kinetic energy is not preserved the collision is said to be **inelastic**. The only exception to this rule is if the colliding objects merge together to become one body in which case they do not lose contact and the collision is said to be **perfectly inelastic**.

> Can objects move during a collision-elastic collisions?

Yes, objects can move together while in contact during collision. This does not make any difference to determining whether the collision is elastic or inelastic as we are interested in what happens just before bodies make contact and just after the bodies lose contact.

Comment: So in the case of the objects sticking together in an inelastic collusion, there would have to be some deformation?

Comment: @Andromeda Correct, some fraction or the *“contact force”* causes permanent material deformation, which is how energy is dissipated. External forces too can dissipate energy during collision, such as friction force.

Answer (score 0):

Total energy of the system: before and after the elastic collision: $E_b = E_{kb} = E_{ka} = E_a$

During the $\delta t$ of contact: $E = E_k + E_p$, where $E_p$ is the repulsive electrostatic potential energy. $E = E_b = E_a$.

It is not a temporary inelastic collision. What matters is the kinetic energy before and after it.